# Proof that if $f_n\to f$ a.e., $g_n \to g$ a.e. and $g_n = f_n$ a.e. implies $f=g$ a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, almost-everywhere

So I am to prove that, for a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and sequences of extended real-valued measurable functions $f_n,g_n$ from $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ to the extended real line, such that
\begin{equation}\label{1}\tag{1}
    \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n = f  \text{ a.e.}, \quad 
    \lim_{n\to\infty} g_n = g  \text{ a.e.}, \quad 
    \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: f_n = g_n  \text{ a.e.},
\end{equation}

we have $f=g$ a.e..

As an attempt, I let
\begin{equation}
    A := \{\omega\in\Omega : f(\omega) = g(\omega)\},
\end{equation}

such that for
\begin{equation}
    A_n := \{\omega\in\Omega : g_n(\omega) = f_n(\omega)\},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    B_1 := \{\omega\in\Omega : lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(\omega) = f(\omega)\},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    B_2 := \{\omega\in\Omega : lim_{n\to\infty} g_n(\omega) = g(\omega)\},
\end{equation}

we have
\begin{equation}
    \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) \cap B_1 \cap B_2 \subset A,
\end{equation}

i.e.

\begin{equation}
    A^c \subset
    \left[\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) \cap B_1 \cap B_2\right]^c
    = \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n^c\right) \cup B_1^c \cup B_2^c.
\end{equation}

Now, by the subadditivity of measures, and by the assumptions \eqref{1}, $\mu(A^c) = 0$ since
\begin{equation}
    0 \leqslant \mu(A^c) \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n)^c + \mu(B_1^c) + \mu(B_2^c) = 0,
\end{equation}

so it would follow that $f=g$ a.e.. However, since it is not given that $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a complete measure space, we do not know if $A^c\in\mathcal{A}$, so $\mu(A^c)$ may be undefined. Which approach would be appropriate? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In short: even if $A^c$ isn't measurable, it will be contained in some null set which is measurable, and so we treat it as a null set. In fact null-ness can be defined without reference to full-fledged Lebesgue measure theory, as is done in Jordan measure theory.

Comment: since $f_n\to f $ a.e and $g_n \to g$ a.e and $g_n, f_n$ are measurable functions it follows that the set $A=\{x\in X: f(x)=g(x)\}$ is measurable , so your proof can be complete!

Comment: Actually i am wrong  the above statement that i told you works only if you have complete measure space . So i think Ian is right you have to go the complete measure space of $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and find an $E \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $A\subset E$.

Comment: But if I were to follow this advice, then I could only prove that $f=g$ a.e. with respect to the completion $\bar\mu$ of $\mu$. Can I assume this is equivalent? The question is not specific about which measure it should concern, so I assume it should be simply $\mu$.

Answer (score 1):

$B_1^c$ and $B_2^c$ and each $A_n^c$ is a null set so $D=B_1^c\cup B_2^c\cup (\cup_nA_n^c)$ is a null set, and $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x\in D^c.$

It may be that $f(x)=g(x)$ for some $x\in D$ but that is moot. We do not want to show that the complement of $S=\{x:f(x)=g(x)\}$ is null. If the measure is incomplete then $S^c$ may  be a non-measurable set. What we need is a null set $D\supset S^c$.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I wrote after substitution S := A?