# If $f_n \longrightarrow f$ almost everywhere and $g_n \longrightarrow g$ almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere, measurable-functions

[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2625108/proof-that-if-f-n-to-f-a-e-g-n-to-g-a-e-and-g-n-f-n-a-e-implies-f?rq=1) The Riemann function $f:[-1,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, &\textrm{if }x \notin \mathbb{Q}\cap[-1,1]\textrm{ or }x =0\\
\frac{1}{q} , &\textrm{if }x\in \mathbb{Q} \cap[-1,1]\textrm{ and }x =\frac{p}{q}\neq 0
\end{cases}
$$

Where $x =\frac{p}{q}$ is an irreducible fraction and q is non zero ($q\neq o)$

Does the Lebesgue Criterion for Riemann Integrability hold for this function?

[2] If $f_n \longrightarrow f$ almost everywhere and $g_n \longrightarrow g$ almost everywhere where $f,g$ are both finite valued, then show that

$f_n+g_n \longrightarrow f+g$ almost everywhere And

$f_ng_n \longrightarrow fg$ almost everywhere

**MY ATTEMPT**

[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2625108/proof-that-if-f-n-to-f-a-e-g-n-to-g-a-e-and-g-n-f-n-a-e-implies-f?rq=1) YES!

$f$ is discontinuous at any rational point $x =\frac{p}{q}$ $(q \neq0)$ and continuous at any irrational point in [-1,1] and f is bounded.

Since $A= \mathbb{Q} \cap[-1,1]$ -{0}the set of discontinuous points of f. Hence $m(A)=0$

Therefore by Lebesgue Criterion for Riemann integrability $f$ is Riemann integrable on [-1,1] Hence $f$ is Lebesgue Integrable and

$\int^{1}_{-1} f(x) dx = \int_{[-1,1]} fdm=0$ because $f=0$ almost everywhere

IS this correct?

[2] I'm not sure how to approach this question. I've tried using [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2625108/proof-that-if-f-n-to-f-a-e-g-n-to-g-a-e-and-g-n-f-n-a-e-implies-f?rq=1)

but I am unable to see the connection if there is any at all. Never did a question like this so i'm unsure as to how to begin.

Comment: Don't link documents. For (2) just take a null set $N$ such that outside of it both $f_n$ and $g_n$ converge. You are reduced to sequences of real (or complex) numbers.

Comment: You should require $q>0$ or the function is not well-defined (because $\frac pq=\frac{-p}{-q}$). I already added the requirement that $p\neq 0$ for you.

Comment: Ok i've fixed part (1) but i'm still pretty confused about part (2). Anything else you can tell me mate?